# How to set a line spacing in a text of a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

```
txt.setText("abc \n defgh");
```

I want to have line spacing to be some value.
Sample range 5 dp.

```
abc
'5dp range'
defgh
```

Comment: What is a "range" in this context?

Comment: What do you mean by "range"?

Comment: Inter-word spacing. I am sorry for my English :)

Comment: use line spacing in xml

Comment: as marginBottom 5dp but one TextView

Comment: previously I didn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `android:lineSpacingExtra` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra) and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
    android:text="abc \n defgh"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I show you how to do this.

First: there are two ways for do it

> **Design (.xml)**
>   I'll separated these: (Full names) and (Years)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notice_event"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Gustavo Tufiño Fernández \n 21 Years Old"/>
```

Nice solution, right?, but if you want do this dynamic, What would you do?

> **Class (Activity/Fragment/Adapters) Dynamic form**

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // put values I need in String variables
            String title = listNoticiasEventosFinal.get(0).getTitle();
            String detail = listNoticiasEventosFinal.get(0).getDescription();

            //Concat Strings with linespace and put int TextView
            String final_text = title + System.getProperty ("line.separator") + detail;
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notice_event);
            textView.setText(final_text);
    }
```

I hope I have help you, regards (Y)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use "lineSpacingExtra". It will works, happy coding **

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"/>
```